# Is there an API to retrieve Sites usage quota

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-admin-sdk

I found AdminReports.CustomerUsageReports.get(date) function can return usage reports such as gmail, Drive and G+. Is there an API can also retrieve Sites usage?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the admin sdk. First, to collect Sites usage, setup Google Analytics https://support.google.com/sites/answer/97459?hl=en on your site(s). Then use Google Analytics via the UI or API https://developers.google.com/analytics/ or Apps Script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics to retrieve the usage data.

Comment: I'd looked at Google Analytics before asking this question. Neither web UI or API does Site quota(usage) report.

Comment: Like any website, Analytics for sites gives you things like sessions, page views, searches. I don't think you can get the sites disk usage quotas or number of programmatically created pages quotas anywhere. Which quota are you specifically interested in?